# Histogram does not show in pairplot

Tags: seaborn

Please help me
Why when I use hue attribute, the histogram is not shown in the graph?

code:

```
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
        import pandas as pd 
        import seaborn as sb 
        my_array =[
                         ['Galaxy S8', 'Android', 64, 4, 149.0 ,'Samsung' ,5.8],
                         ['Lumia950' ,'windows' ,32, 3 ,150.0 ,'Microsoft', 5.2],
                         ['Xpreia L1', 'Android', 16, 2, 180.0,'Sony' ,5.5],
                         ['iphone 7', 'ios', 128 ,2, 138.0 ,'Apple' ,4.7],
                         ['U Ultra', 'Android', 64, 4 ,170.0, 'HTC', 5.7],
                         ['Galaxy S5' ,'Android', 16 ,2, 145.0 ,'Samsung' ,5.1],
                         ['iphone 5s', 'ios', 32, 1, 112.0 ,'Apple' ,4.0],
                         ['Moto G5' ,'Android' ,16, 3 ,144.5 ,'Motorola', 5.0],
                         ['Pixel', 'Android' ,128 ,4 ,143.0 ,'Google' ,5.0]   
                        ]
        smart_phones = pd.DataFrame(my_array , index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] , 
        columns=['Name', 'OS', 'Capacity' ,'Ram', 'Weight', 'Company', 'inch'])

        sb.pairplot(smart_phones , hue="Name" , palette="hls" ,plot_kws={'s':80})

        plt.show();
```

error:

```
        C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:140: 
        RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
          keepdims=keepdims)
        C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:132: 
        RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
          ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

Thank you for replying

Comment: I wonder what kind of plot you'd expect, given that each category appears only once in the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to view a pairplot with this data, you will need to either remove the `hue` parameter or change it to something like `hue='OS'`

The reason for this being it does not make sense to have the hue be the Name of each phone, as each value is different from the last.

Here is an example using `sb.pairplot(smart_phones , hue='OS',palette="hls" ,plot_kws={'s':80})`

[image]